# Does AWS lambda have to use cloudwatch?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I don't much like using Cloudwatch as a logs solution but it seems AWS lambda is tied to using it.  Is this absolutely the case or can I pipe logs from lambda elsewhere without having to pay for or use Cloudwatch at all?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to use CloudWatch. If your Lambda does not have CloudWatch permissions it can't write to it.

Obviously, you can use any other logging framework that allows you to write to a third party service.

You can also use the Lambda Logs API of the underlying runtime to send logs to another service: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/runtimes-logs-api.html

There are a lot of options.